# Connecting to SQL Server; two websites connecting to the same database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, authentication

I am reproducing a Dev site which points to the same database of the live one just for code changes.

```
meta.ConnectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=CBAHWEB\SQLEXPRESS;Database=livedatabasename;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
meta.CommandTimeout = 600
meta.open
```

but I keep getting the cannot log in error on the new dev site

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80004005'
>
> Cannot open database "livedatabasename" requested by the login. The login failed.
>
> /dbcommon/connectionfile.php, line 8

Anyone got some tip on where to start fixing this issue?

Comment: Did you provided the username and password?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty it is using the windows login method, and I have also tried creating a username and password to login with.

Comment: actually I Changed the ownership of new user and seems to worked out. Can you post as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This error occurs when you have configured your application with IIS, and IIS goes to SQL Server and tries to login with credentials that do not have proper permissions. This error can also occur when replication or mirroring is set up.

Quoted directly from [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/20/sql-server-fix-error-cannot-open-database-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed-login-failed-for-user-nt-authoritynetwork-service/)